# C# WPF Передать View в ViewModel при ItemsSource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Есть TabControl с ItemsSource и биндингом к TabItem с ViewModel. Как мне передать в TabItem ViewModel TabItem View?

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}">
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TabItem">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Header}"/>
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding Content}"/>
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
        </Style>
    </TabControl.Resources>
</TabControl>
```

Comment: *Как мне передать в TabItem ViewModel TabItem View?* — чего?

Comment: view в view model

Comment: Tabs класса Tab, как мне туда передать tab item?

Comment: используя setter и биндюсь к свойствам, а как мне в конструктор передать сам контрол?

Comment: мне нужно делать анимацию когда я изменяю свойство

Comment: Эээ, вы не должны передавать V в VM ни в коем случае, это неправильно. Да и анимация это чисто вьюшная задача, VM ничего не должна о ней знать

Comment: Опишите подробнее, что конкретно вы хотите сделать

Comment: Tabs - коллекция Tab, в Tab есть свойство Background (SolidColorBrush), я хочу чтобы TabItem header мигал цветом Background когда он не null или например когда какое-небудь другое свойство - true

Comment: Цвет таба это часть бизнес-логики?

Comment: @АндрейNOP  да, именно

Comment: Для таких вещей как изменение цвета таба на основании значения свойства нужно использовать [триггеры](https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/10.2.php).

Comment: @Bulson, моргание триггером?

Comment: @АндрейNOP само по себе моргание - это анимация, а запускаться она должна с помощью триггера.

Comment: @Bulson DataTrigger?